# Error al alinear formulario Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3

Estoy presentando un problema al momento de alinear mi formulario y es que cuando le doy click a un `inputtext` como si lo fuera a ingresar, lo valida y me sale su respectivo mensaje y hace el nombre del `textArea` **Descripcion** se mueva`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'idArea')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'Nombre')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'Descripcion')->textarea(['maxlength' => true, 'rows' => "5"]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: ¿cuál respuesta sirvió?

Comment: Aun ninguna, el titulo del textArea se sigue moviendo

Comment: En la respuesta mía explico que funciona correctamente el código de Bootstrap, lo cual quiere decir que lo estás implementando mal o estás configurando mal los campos que llamas en el plugin de Yii.

Answer (score 2):

Con el código básico de Bootstrap funciona perfectamente adaptándolo a tu layout del formulario, tendrías que revisar como está generando el HTML tu plugin de Bootstrap o la versión específica de Bootstrap utilizada en el mismo:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="exampleInput1">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput1" placeholder="First name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please type your first name.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label for="exampleInput2">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInput2" placeholder="Last name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please type your last name.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" required></textarea>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please type something.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar al cerrar el `</div>` abajo poner un salto de línea con un `<br>`
para que el título de descripción quede un poco más abajo y el mensaje de error de tu input text se vea normal y no se mueva el otro. Saludos.

Comment: Ya lo intente amigo, pero no me funciono

Comment: Hmm, que raro.
O también puedes usar la etiqueta **<hr>**, para dividir la sección te dejo un ejemplo aquí. 
(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_hr_default_css)

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes probar a ponerle una `id` al `div` en el que esta descripción y por css ponerle un margen superior por ejemplo `margin-top: 20px;`

O sino crear `div` vacio en el medio y ponerle una altura de 20px por ejemplo, `height: 20px;`